# Can i use a SATA 6gb/s hard disk with a M2N68-AM motherboard?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

So I have a M2N68-AM motherboard from ASUS: http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=2UWzsrOiRbMPGYpw And I would like to buy this hard disk: http://www.emag.ro/hard_disk-uri/hdd-western-digital-caviar-black-15tb-7200rpm-64mb-sata3--pWD1502FAEX?ref=hp_rec_1

It`s compatible and is this the best choice ?

Answer (score 0):

A 6GB drive will work in a 3GB port, and I think the speed will be fine too. If you want really fast speed though, instead of buying a 7200 rpm drive, you should get a small SSD (for programs only). Then a cheap slow 60 USD 1 TB drive for movies, music, etc.